# Python - Is there anyway to grasp all values of object create by a class into a list automatically

Tags: python, class, oop

I have this exercise: Find the oldest cat

```
#Given the below class:
class Cat:
    species = 'mammal'
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


# 1 Instantiate the Cat object with 3 cats 
cat1 = Cat('Tom', 5)
cat2 = Cat('Jerry', 2)
cat3 = Cat('Lucas', 10)


# 2 Create a function that finds the oldest cat
def FindOldest():
    cat_age = [cat1.age, cat2.age, cat3.age]
    cat_age.sort(reverse = True)
    oldest_cat = cat_age[0]
    return print(f'The oldest cat is {oldest_cat} years old.')


# 3 Print out: "The oldest cat is x years old.". x will be the oldest cat age by using the function in #2

FindOldest()
```

Above is my way to find the oldest cat. What I wanna ask is there anyway for me to grasp the cat_age automatic if the object is update more than 3 cat (maybe in the future i will add more object), is there anyway to dynamic it.

Comment: Don't do it. Consider instead instantiating your cats in a list or a dictionary and then iterate through it. There are many good arguments and alternatives here: [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are two ways to have a list of all `Cat` objects.

The bad method involves asking Python for all objects tracked by the garbage collector, then filtering the `Cat` ones. Note that even an empty program will have a ton of objects already floating around.

```
import gc

all_cats = [obj for obj in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(obj, Cat)]
```

The good method requires keeping track of all created `Cat` objects. The easiest way to do this is to modify the class constructor to keep tabs in a static field:

```
class Cat:
    members = []
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        # ...
        self.members.append(self)

# ...
```

Then, to find all cats, you can use

```
all_cats = Cat.members
```

To get all cats sorted by age, use the `key` parameter:

```
cats_by_age = all_cats.sorted(key=lambda cat: cat.age, reverse=True)
oldest_cat = cats_by_age[0]
```

If you know you will often want the oldest cat, you might want to look into [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) to avoid the sorting at the point of query, moving it into the insertion process.

Answer (score -1):

Your code doesn't find the oldest `cat`, it find its age. You should also decide if you want the function to print the results or return them, `return print(...)` will just return `None`.

You can use `max` with `key` `cat.age` to find the oldest one. This will check all the `cat`s in the list regardless its size

```
cat1 = Cat('Tom', 5)
cat2 = Cat('Jerry', 2)
cat3 = Cat('Lucas', 10)

cats = [cat1, cat2, cat3]

def find_oldest():
    return max(cats, key=lambda cat: cat.age)


oldest_cat = find_oldest()
print(f'The oldest cat is {oldest_cat.name}, {oldest_cat.age} years old.')
```

If you still want to use `sort`

```
def find_oldest():
    return sorted(cats, key=lambda cat: cat.age)[-1]
```